# Excel Delete row if in named range

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row, named-ranges

I have a worksheet with protected cells. There's an 'add row' button and I need a 'delete row' button. HOWEVER, I only want the user to be able to delete the row if it is within a named range.

> > ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
> >
> > If "**selected row**" within Range("ProjectList") Then
> >
> > ```
> >      Row.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
> > ```
> >
> > End If
> >     ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Intersect to check this:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("ProjectList")) Is Nothing Then
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
```